# Trying to create a child theme with plugin

Tags: themes

What do I need to change,  Please
I receive this a number of times

> Notice:  Undefined index: image_title in
>   /home/wwwcane/public_html/tiny/wp-content/themes/beaver/header.php on
>   line 131

```
foreach( $slAr as $sv ){

  $n++; ?><img src="<?php echo esc_url($sv['image_src']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($sv['image_title']);?>" title="<?php echo /* line #131 */
  '#sl.lidecaption'.$n ; ?>"/><?php

  $slideno[] = $n;

}
```

Comment: Can you please write header.php code so i can check it and give you solution.

Comment: The notice is saying that the `image_src` item doesn't exist in the array. You can do `var_dump( $sv );` to see the items in the `$sv` array. And to avoid the notice, you could do `if ( isset( $sv['image_src'] ) ) { ... }`. Or update whatever the resource is and be sure to use proper values.